# How can I edit Graphite Python source files to debug?

Tags: python, debugging, graphite

I'm using the Graphite charting library and I'd like to edit the source files to debug a problem.

Specifically, I'd like to edit graphite/webapp/graphite/render/gylph.py drawGraph() function.

But when I change the code and render a chart, which was producing an error in that area of the code, my edited code does not seem to execute.

In fact I can delete that entire file and the pyc file and the code still seems to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in debugger of python, pdb. 
Put in the source you want to edit:

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

just before the place you want to stop execution and examine the problem.

Comment: I think the problem is that even though I edit the py file, my changes don't seem to be recognized. So if I were to put your code in the file, it would not execute.

Comment: Actually, for some reason now it runs, but I'm trying to open a file for write, its not letting me. [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'greg.txt' I tried setting the folder owner to www-data but no luck.